# setinterval method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button which triggers the function inside set interval every 1 sec.
The value of the button changes to stop. When I hit stop I call the clearinterval method.
For some reason the clear interval method is not working.

This is my input

```
<input id="trigger" type="button" value="start"/>
```

my js function

```
$(function() {
    $('#trigger').click(function() {
        var timerId = 0;
        var trigger = $('#trigger').val();

        if(trigger == 'start') {
            timerId = setInterval(function() {
                $('#trigger').val('stop');
                main();
            }, 1000);
        } else if(trigger == 'stop') {
                clearInterval(timerId);
                $('#trigger').val('start');                
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have timerId is defined to be local to the scope of click(), so when you run it the second time (in the stop event) it will be 0 again. Try this

```
var timerId = 0;
$(function() {
    $('#trigger').click(function() {
        var trigger = $('#trigger').val();

        if(trigger == 'start') {
            timerId = setInterval(function() {
                $('#trigger').val('stop');
                main();
            }, 1000);
        } else if(trigger == 'stop') {
                clearInterval(timerId);
                $('#trigger').val('start');                
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are re-initialising  the timerId every time #trigger is clicked. Move the  `var timerId = 0;` outside the click function

Comment: @YeshwanthVenkatesh No problem, its easily done! You should accept one of the answers you got as you're still getting questions about other parts of the code :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten Why to accept?.. it was just an "overlook" ;) joke